# how to store user input value in local variable(in view) in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to declare a local variable in my razor html form (view) and want to store user input value in that local variable.And then want to use that variable in foreach loop .in mvc 5 i am new to asp.net.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddQuestion", "admin", new { id = ViewBag.qf_id }, FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Question Statement</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Ques.QuestionString, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Ques.QuestionString)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>No. of option you want to add for this question </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     @{var val = @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.counter, new { @class = "form-control" }); }


    </div>
</div>
         foreach(var item in val)
         {

             @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Ans.AnswerStatement)

         }

 <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
 </div>
  }
```

Comment: I don't see its a good approach. What if user didn't entered anything? you must use DisplayTemplates / EditorTemplates for that

Comment: To add multiple textboxes in view it is better using `EditorTemplates` with control value passed by client-side event.

Comment: how i can integrate it in my code ?

Comment: If you are hoping to do this client-side it wont work you would need to use javascript (No clear in question). On Server side Assuming val is an int you would want to use a "for loop" and not a foreach. `code`@{var val = @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.counter, new { @class = "form-control" }); }`code` should be split in to two lines. `code`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.counter, new { @class = "form-control" });`code`  and `code`@{var val = a.counter }`code`. You seem to be setting val to html otherwise

Comment: can you tell me coded example to cater this work?//

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work unless it gets adapted to 1 of 2 solutions:

1) The only way this works is if the use enters a value in the textbox, then posts back to the controller, and the controller inputs this variable into the model, which the view then re-renders, using the number in the model, with the desired number of entries.  That's the web forms way and is inefficient.

2) Using JavaScript, when a user enters a number, JavaScript can either render the markup using a templating framework, or make a request to the server, get the individual data, and return a partial view as HTML.

Comment: It's not directly relevant, but I used to do similar things using kendo and a listview; I don't know if this blog post will help but it might be helpful to understand the integration maybe?  https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/asp-net-mvc-and-client-side-lists-with-kendo/

Comment: can you tell me coded way to cater this kind of work?